# React - How to change the text of accordion heading of the current clicked item

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, accordion

I am making a simple Reactjs accordion application in which collapse and expanding of each individual items are done.

**Requirement:**

A simple requirement is that I am in the need to toggle the text of the heading as **Expand** or **Shrink** based on the click.

If we click any of the item then the content will gets displayed in that case the text changes to Shrink as because the accordion gets opened so the Shrink title is given for closing of the accordion.

**Complete working example:**

> **https://codesandbox.io/s/react-accordion-forked-lcyr0**

In the above example I have used the following code to change the text,

**Accordion.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Text from "./text";
import Heading from "./heading";
import getAccordion from "./GetAccordion";

const Accordion = getAccordion(1);

const accordionData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    content: "This is a first content"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    content: "This is a second content"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    content: "This is a third content"
  }
];

const NormalAccordion = () => {
  const [toggleValue, setToggleValue] = useState(-1);

  const toggleHandler = (index) => {
    setToggleValue(index);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {accordionData.map((item, index) => (
        <Accordion>
          <Heading>
            <div
              style={{ padding: "10px", cursor: "pointer" }}
              className="heading"
              onClick={() => toggleHandler(index)}
            >
              {toggleValue !== index ? `Expand` : `Shrink`}
            </div>
          </Heading>
          <Text>{item.content}</Text>
        </Accordion>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default NormalAccordion;
```

And this line `` {toggleValue !== index ? `Expand` : `Shrink`} `` changes the text once but after that it doesn't make any changes on further toggle over the title(Expand/Shrink).

Kindly help me to achieve the result of toggling the text between Expand and Shrink based on the respective clicks.

Comment: Yiu have to use state each header status item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reset the `toggleValue` if the item is already clicked :

```
  const toggleHandler = (index) => {

    index===toggleValue?setToggleValue(-1): setToggleValue(index);
  };
```

then use condition to render the current content:

```
<Text>{toggleValue === index && item.content}</Text>
```

and simplify the `Text` component to this one :

```
<div style={{ ...this.props.style }}>
        <div className={`content ${this.props.text ? "open" : ""}`}>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Could you also please provide the codesandbox example because I see the texts are not changing in right way if we keep on toggling the headings of different accordion. Your solution here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-accordion-forked-kkt2d .. Please help me to only show expand when respective accordion is closed and shrink when it is opened.

Comment: you could check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-accordion-forked-vc5zr) i simplified the Text component code and i added conditional rendering `<Text>{toggleValue === index && item.content}</Text>`

Answer (score 1):

You should use boolean value as an accordion can have 2 values.

#### Idea:

- Create a standalone accourdion component which defines a behavior of expand/ collapse.
- Create a wrapper view component that calls this this component.
- Pass your data as a prop from this view instead of using a local hard coded object.

Benefit of this approach is that you have 2 modular components that work only on props. These can be exported later to their own standalone library.

Ideally, a component should be dumb and should only know its own behavior based on state and props.

[Updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-accordion-forked-xu8ll?file=/constants/accordion-data.js)

- Accoirdion component changes

```js
const [toggleValue, setToggleValue] = useState(false);

const toggleHandler = () => {
  setToggleValue(!toggleValue);
};
```

- Accordion view changes

```js
const AccordionView = ({ accordionData }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {accordionData.map((item) => (
        <NormalAccordion content={item.content} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

- Constants: I create a folder called constants that will hold hardcoded objects and then we pass it using props from `index.js`

```js
export const accordionData = [{
    id: 1,
    content: "This is a first content"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    content: "This is a second content"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    content: "This is a third content"
  }
];
```

- Changes in `index.js`

```js
import { accordionData } from '../constants/accordion-data'

...

<NormalAccordion accordionData={ accordionData } />
```

Comment: This will make changes to all the accordion at once.. But I am in the need to apply the solution to clicked accordion alone..

Comment: I was about to update my asnwer for that. Please give me couple of mins to update it

Comment: Could you please check the sandbox, It gives me error as ```Cannot read property 'map' of undefined``` ..

Comment: What are the ```constants``` changes I need to make? I clicked the above updated sandbox link and it throws the above said error..

Comment: I didn't try any changes in my code.. I tried running your sandbox alone that itself gave me error.. Could you please open the sandbox in incognito mode and verify whether it is working? I can see a constants folder but the file is empty there.. Not sure whether your changes have been saved..

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, However while implementing the solution in my real app, I feel the other solution as a straight forward answer and it solves the issue the way I want.. I have upvoted your answer and I really appreciate your time and efforts..